# Filter lines based on length using sed and grep

Tags: grep, sed

How to locate lines longer than 100 and smaller than 150 characters using `sed` and `grep`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command

```
sed -nr '/^.{101,149}$/p' infile
```

#### Breaking down:

- `-n`: no printing

The `-n` option will prevent to print anything unless an explicit request to print is found (`^.{101,149}$` "*Lines longer than 100(>=101) and smaller than 150 characters(<=149)*"). The `/p` flag used as one way to turn printing back on.

- `-r`: -r (--regexp-extended)

The `-r` enables the Extended regular expressions. replace `-r` with `-E` if your sed doesn't recognize it or you will need to escape the curly braces if none of them supported in your version of sed. Then the command would be `sed -n '/^.\{101,149\}$/p' infile`.

- The `^` is just the anchor for beginning of line and the `$` for end of line.
- A single `.` matches any single character

So, you got it, with `sed -nr '/^.{101,149}$/p' infile`, we are looking for a line from start to end of it which has or contains our defined rule.

<sub>*This is a way to duplicate the function of `grep` with `sed` e.g: `sed -n '/.../p'` :)*</sub>

#### Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) command

```
grep -E '^.{101,149}$' infile
```

- `-E` this is the same as sed's `-r` option but for `grep` command. So if you don't want to use is just escape the curly braces.

#### Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command

```
awk 'length($0)>100 && length($0)<150' infile
```

- `length` return the length of the line. In awk, the `$0` specifies the whole line. So if the length of line was between 100 and 150, will be print out.

Comment: @user2280915 If this post solved your question, you can mark this as the answer.

Comment: It's better to use `sed -E` isntead of `sed -r`, `-E` can work with BSD sed, too.

Comment: @KaiyA. This perfectly solves my problem.  Thanks

Comment: @Ron thanks for making my question more readable and understandable

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this using `bash`:

```
while read l; do nc=$(<<< "$l" wc -c); [ $nc -ge 101 ] && [ $nc -le 149 ] && echo "$l"; done < file
```

Expanded into a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read l; do
    nc=$(<<< "$l" wc -c)
    if [ $nc -ge 101 ]; then
        if [ $nc -le 149 ]; then
            echo "$l"
        fi
    fi
done < file
```

Comment: my question is related with grep and Sed. Anyways thanks for answer